# ¿ Como generar una identificación de usuario única para cada usuario en un python app?

Tags: python, identity, slack-api

Estoy desarrollando un chatbot desde [este repositorio](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial) y quiero que él pueda identifiar el usuario. ¿Entonces sabe cómo obtener algo en línea que puede generar una identificación de usuario única para cada usuario (los ID de usuario para la investigación deben tener la capacidad de almacenarse de forma anónima) ? Por el momento solo se interconecta con Slack

```
from rasa_core.channels import HttpInputChannel
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_slack_connector import SlackInput

nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/weathernlu')
agent = Agent.load('./models/dialogue',interpreter = nlu_interpreter)

# https://api.slack.com/apps/AASPDV196/oauth?
input_channel = SlackInput('OAuth Access Token','Bot User OAuth Access Token',
'Verification Token',True)

agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5004,'/',input_channel))
```

Y utilisar `uuid.uuid4()` pero no estoy seguro. También estoy pensando en crear una página real que registre usuarios, pero no estoy seguro de que permita a Slack. Slack no es obligatorio pero, aparte de la terminal, no tengo ninguna otra interfaz de comunicación Chatbox por el momento.